# UITapGestureRecognizer in photos coming from firebase

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm doing a project where I get photos from the database and the ready ones in a collection view, how can I add the UITapGestureRecognizer to all the photos that are uploaded from the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:))))

func imageTapped(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.item)
}
```

Above code may help you to add gesture in image view.

Comment: I already do in the first photo, but I'm only able to do it in the first one and do not replicate in the undetermined photos that may appear in the database

Comment: my code is https://gist.github.com/vdst1/e0980ef4b7184353ab0c83ff4b7c8314

Comment: have you used collection view ?

Comment: yes and within the view of the collection has a cell with a view of the image

Comment: Then you can use UICollectionViewDelegate method i.e
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: and this will make when clicking on all the images they appear fullscreen?

Comment: Hope so, please try it...!

Comment: but where do I use this method? I'm new to this

Comment: Below "cellForItemAt" method

Comment: function within function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed a check for which image you are clicking? For that you can assign table cell's index to imageView tag. Just like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellIedntifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionImageClicked(_:)))
    cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    return cell
}

@objc func actionImageClicked(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let index = (recognizer.view as! UIImageView).tag

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add UITapGestureRecognizer for each UIImageView in cell

```
 import UIKit

 class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

 @IBOutlet private weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

 var imageViewTappedClosure: ((CollectionViewCell?,UIImageView?) -> Void)?

 override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()

   myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imgViewTapped))
   myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }


 func setContent() {

 }

 @objc private func imgViewTapped() {
    imageViewTappedClosure?(self,myImageView)
 }

}
```

When you tap in UIImageView, you can check what  UIImageView was tapped. (or image in UIImageView)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 123
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageViewTappedClosure = { cell, imageView in

      //insert your implement code when you tap in ImageView in your cell
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```